# How to set the opacity of this marker

Tags: leaflet

How can I switch the opacity of this marker based on the selected radio option inside popup?

```
L.marker([-14.604847, 30.234375],)
   .bindPopup('<input type="radio" id="on" name="switch" value="on"><label for="on">ON</label><input type="radio" id="off" name="gender" value="off">
<label for="off">OFF</label><input type="radio" id="other" name="switch" value="other">')
   .addTo(map);
```

for example, I clicked "On" and then the marker's opacity is changed to 1 and when I click off it changes to opacity 0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a reference for your marker, listen to `popupopen` event and then listen using  `L.DomEvent` to each checkbox change event. Once it is for on, set the marker opacity to 1, once it is for off, set it for 0.3. I am sure it can be achieved with even less code but it can get you started.

```
 marker.on('popupopen', function(popup) {
    L.DomEvent.on(
      document.getElementById('off'),
      'change',
      (ev) => marker.setOpacity(0.3));
    L.DomEvent.on(
      document.getElementById('on'),
      'change',
      (ev) => marker.setOpacity(1));
 })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==" crossorigin=""></script>



</head>

<body>



  <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  <script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([-14.604847, 30.234375], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
      maxZoom: 18,
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
      id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
      tileSize: 512,
      zoomOffset: -1
    }).addTo(map);


    const marker = L.marker([-14.604847, 30.234375])
      .bindPopup('<input type="radio" id="on" name="switch" value="on"><label for="male">ON</label><br><input type="radio" id="off" name="switch" value="off"><label for="female">OFF</label>')
      .addTo(map)




    marker.on('popupopen', function(popup) {
      L.DomEvent.on(
        document.getElementById('off'),
        'change',
        (ev) => marker.setOpacity(0.3));
      L.DomEvent.on(
        document.getElementById('on'),
        'change',
        (ev) => marker.setOpacity(1));
    })
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: is it possible to select marker via its options instead of var. something like this
`L.marker([56.944974, 133.59375], { divId: 6,}).addTo(map)`. so i want to select the marker using `divId:6`

Comment: There is no `divId` option on documented [marker options](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#marker-option) so I guess it is not possible.

Comment: or selecting all markers instead? because I had to make the popupopen function on each marker

Comment: I think you should ask this in a new question as in this question you only asked about only one marker and not many.